# ethernet bridge questions

Tags: network-bridge

I have a Dell laptop running Ubuntu 20.04 that has both an ethernet and a wifi card.  It is connected to a home router via wifi.  I would like to connect a Raspberry Pi to the home network via the Dell ethernet card (the Pi's wifi card functions poorly).

I've tried setting up a bridge on the Ubuntu laptop but can't get it to work, so I have some questions:

1. Does the bridge set up a subnet?  If it does, that's a non-starter as I want the Pi to be on the same network as the other devices attached to the router.
2. If the bridge does not set up a subnet, is there a place where I can read about the appropriate configuration for this setup?
3. In particular, I have not found any site that says what to do with the Raspberry Pi - only how to set up the Ubuntu bridge.  I would like the Pi to have a static IP address.  Beyond setting that in the Pi's /etc/dhcpcd.conf file, is there anything else to do on the client side.  Should the IP address but inserted anywhere in the bridge configuration?

An addendum: the laptop bridge can 'see' the RPi via its ethernet card (3rd entry; the 1st two entries are the laptop ethernet card):

```
$ brctl showmacs br0
port no mac addr    is local?   ageing timer
  1 84:8f:69:cf:0a:f8   yes        0.00
  1 84:8f:69:cf:0a:f8   yes        0.00
  1 b8:27:eb:c7:84:53   no         0.55
```

I cannot ssh into the RPi using the static IP address assigned to its own eth0, even though I can occasionally ssh into it using a different static IP for its wifi card.  I am clearly missing something.

Second addendum: There are many postings that state that one cannot bridge wifi to eth0, or at least without 4addr capability. See, for example,

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363332/how-do-i-configure-a-network-interface-bridge-from-wifi-to-ethernet-with-debian

I tried setting up 4addr capability, and I believe the result is that the RPi connected through the laptop via eth0, but on a subnet, so the rest of the home network cannot see it. This is not a useful solution for me.

So far I have not found any posted solution for a wifi-eth0 bridge in which the connected eth0 device is on the same network as the wifi router.

It looks like the best option short of stringing a lot of ethernet cable is to use a pair of power ethernet adapters.

Comment: Is connecting to the router via the RPi directly with an ethernet cable an option?  (That's actually the *better* faster option than trying to bridge and set up proper network routing rules to let data flow properly from the RPi through teh Dell to the rest of the network)

Comment: No.  The router is on another floor of the house, with no easy way to string ethernet cable.  The RPi is running several sensors through its GPIO board, and  those plus the wifi card represent too much of a power load (I already have the maximum current from the power supply), but the system runs without failure with an ethernet connection.